# Observable merge with pipe operator in RxJS version 6

Tags: rxjs6

I am using RxJS 6 which now uses the pipe operator. I have this:

```
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';

const rs1 = new ReplaySubject(1); 
const rs2 = new ReplaySubject(1);
const rs3 = new ReplaySubject(1);

rs1.next(1);
rs2.next(2);
rs3.next(3);

Observable.merge(rs1,rs2,rs3).subscribe(v => {

});
```

but this doesn't compile - Observable.merge is not defined. I might be looking for concat instead of merge, but either way, concat is not defined as a static method on the Observable constructor either - how can we use merge and concat with RxJS7?

Answer (score 2):

They changed a few things with version 6, this now works for me:

```
import {concat, Observable, merge} from 'rxjs';
import {BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, pipe} from "rxjs";
import {takeUntil, takeWhile} from 'rxjs/operators';


const rs1 = new ReplaySubject(1);  
const rs2 = new ReplaySubject(1);
const rs3 = new ReplaySubject(1);

rs1.next(1);
rs2.next(2);
rs3.next(2);

merge(rs1,rs2,rs3).pipe(takeWhile(() => true)).subscribe(v => {

  console.log({v});
});
```